# I want to change the page background color, but it doesn't work as I expect in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a new JavaScript learner, and I want change the background color of my page, so I wrote a page below:

```js
function change_color() {
  console.log('6666');
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  alert("the color has changed to green!");
  console.log('6666');
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="change_color()">change color</button>
```

I expect that the function should change the background color **to green first**, then show the popup window, then change the background color to blue. But it runs differently in Chrome, **the page doesn't change to green before the popup window**, it only changes to blue, I don't see the process of changing to green. 
**If I open the page by Edge or Firefox, it works well, but if I open the page by Chrome 67.0.3396.40 or Chrome 66.0.3359.170, the page doesn't change to green before the popup window**. Why?

Comment: If you want to pause the script execution, you shouldn't rely on alert. In fact you shouldn't try to pause the execution at all. Instead you should define a behavior triggered by a user input. you can start by trying out [window.confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert` is not required to trigger a DOM rerender, and it also does not so in Chrome (unlike other browsers). To see the intermediate changes, you can use a timeout to insert a delay before the alert. The DOM will be rerendered in that time.

```js
function change_color() {
    console.log('6666');
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    setTimeout(() => {
        alert("the color has changed to green!");
        console.log('6666');
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    });
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="change_color()">change color</button>
```

Comment: this is not an answer to what OP asked.

Comment: can you tell me why chrome is unlike other browsers?

Comment: @peterzhang I'm not aware of any technical reasons. `alert` is a very old API and the specification leaves room for different implementations, not just in the look of the popup windows. Chrome uses [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(web_engine)) to render HTML while Firefox and Safari use other engines, and it's the HTML engine alone that decides how to handle the details.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>666</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function change_color() {
     console.log('6666');
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
     setTimeout(function(){alert("the color has changed to green!"); }, 5);
     console.log('6666');
     setTimeout(function(){document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; }, 5);
}
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="change_color()">change color</button>
</body>

</html>
```

These are UI blocking events. You can put a setTimeout to make it work

```
function change_color() {
     console.log('6666');
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
     setTimeout(function(){alert("the color has changed to green!"); }, 5);
     console.log('6666');
     setTimeout(function(){document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; }, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a if else in there, and set a default background-color to your body with css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>666</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function change_color() {
if(document.body.style.backgroundColor == "blue"){
    console.log('6666');
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    alert("the color has changed to green!");
} else { 
    console.log('6666');
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}}
</script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:blue;">
<button type="button" onclick="change_color();">change color</button>
</body>

</html>
```